# Bounding the size of subspaces of $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

For a subgroup $V$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, define $\Vert V \Vert$ to be the smallest $k$ such that $V$ is generated by its intersection with the closed $k$-ball around the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Also, for $w \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ define $V_w$ to be the set of all $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $x \cdot w = 0$, where $\cdot$ is the usual dot product.

I'm trying to find constants $C_n, D_n \geq 0$ (depending on $n$) such that $\Vert V_w \Vert \leq C_n \Vert w \Vert + D_n$ for all $w \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, where $\Vert w \Vert$ is the usual norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Preferably $C_n < 1$ and $D_n$ is a polynomial in $n$.

I don't really know how to tag this or what sort of buzzwords to focus on while searching for results of this form, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is most naturally phrased in terms of lattices. There have been some study of lattice basis made of vectors of bounded size. See for example [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.03183), or [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.1457). I haven’t seen analogues of your condition on $w$ though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the vector $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z^2$ with $a,b$ relatively prime.  The vector is orthogonal to $(b,-a)$ and there is no shorter vector with that property.  Therefore your constant $C$ must be at least $1$.  In higher dimensions, given a vector $(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n)$, you may want to look at the span of vectors of the form $(a_2,-a_1, 0,\ldots,0)$ (and similarly for other pairs of coordinates).